# how to take the data of a post request and reuse it in another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to angular and still have a lot of confusion.
I would like to ask you a simple question.
I am creating a booking application. I have already entered the first `Post request`  to add the desired reservation. how do you think I can take these booking data and add them under another component? Once the reservation has been made, I need to add it to another component which will show a list of reservations.

Comment: check this out: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You can use NgRx or NgSX kind of libraries. Make a state that holds an array of book reservation. Before you post your request distpatch an action that populates the state.

Comment: This is what services are for. I strongly advise taking an Angular course to learn the basics, I think it could be really helpful for you.

Comment: As you are new to angular, i would advice you to use a service rather than a library like ngrx/ngxs.